# Add additional namespace with XSLT

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I need to add an additional namespace to an already namespaced XML file but only if a particular element does not exist.

**My XML doc looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<everyone xmlns="AAA" xmlns:ns2="BBB" xmlns:ns3="CCC" company="TestingCorp">
    <common>Stuff Here</common>
    <ns2:person id="123">
        <ns3:firstname>Billy</ns3:firstname>
        <ns2:lastname>Bobby</ns2:lastname>
    </ns2:person>
</everyone>
```

... and if there is no ns3:firstname element in the person element, I'd like to add a new namespace and (e.g. xmlns:frog="FFF") and also an additional element within person as shown below:

**Desired Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<everyone xmlns="AAA" xmlns:ns2="BBB" xmlns:ns3="CCC" xmlns:frog="FFF" company="TestingCorp">
    <common>Stuff Here</common>
    <ns2:person id="123">
        <frog:title>
            <Master/>
        </frog:title>
        <ns2:lastname>Bobby</ns2:lastname>
    </ns2:person>
</everyone>
```

**My XSL doc currently is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Copy Everything -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="ns:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="frog">fff</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.... unfortunately this does not work.

I've tried lots of different things but can't seem to achieve this using XSLT v1.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to declare the various namespaces in your stylesheet, as well as the `"AAA"` default namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="AAA"
    xmlns:frog="FFF"
    xmlns:ns2="BBB"
    xmlns:ns3="CCC">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Copy Everything -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <!-- for a Person with no firstname, add a frog:title -->
  <xsl:template match="ns2:person[not(ns3:firstname)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <!-- must handle attributes before elements/text nodes -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
          <frog:title>
              <Master/>
          </frog:title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<everyone xmlns="AAA" xmlns:ns2="BBB" xmlns:ns3="CCC" company="TestingCorp">
    <common>Stuff Here</common>
    <ns2:person id="123">
        <frog:title xmlns:frog="FFF">
            <Master/>
        </frog:title>
        <ns2:lastname>Bobby</ns2:lastname>
    </ns2:person>
</everyone>
```

If the `xmlns:frog` absolutely must be on the `everyone` element rather than on each `frog:title` then you could add another template

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/namespace::frog" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy the namespace declaration off the stylesheet element (though this would mean that every output document has an `xmlns:frog` declaration even if it doesn't involve any `frog:*` elements).

---

Edit: apparently Xalan doesn't like the `copy-of` namespaces from `document('')`, as an alternative, if you know that the document element will always have the same name then you can hard code that as a literal result element

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <everyone xmlns:frog="FFF">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </everyone>
</xsl:template>
```

(technically it will do what you want even without the explicit `xmlns:frog` in this template, since literal result elements always get the namespace declarations that are in scope at the point *in the stylesheet* where they are declared, but the intention is arguably clearer if you include it)

[This mailing list post](http://marc.info/?l=xalan-j-users&m=126391355928870) gives some possible insights into the reason for `document('')` not working as it should.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I'm yet to test this but from my very limited knowledge of XSLT, I can't see how this will only add in the frog:title element if the ns3:firstname element in missing from the person.

Comment: @user2119994 the trick is in the `match="ns2:person[not(ns3:firstname)]"` - this template only applies to `person` elements that don't have a `firstname`, those that do have a firstname will use the identity template instead.

Comment: hi,Also, is there any way of achieving this by specifying only the new namespace I want to add to the root element and copy all existing ones across, without having to specify all the other ones too?

Comment: @user2119994 that's what it's doing.  The `xmlns:ns2` and `xmlns:ns3` on the `xsl:stylesheet` are necessary to make the template match expression valid, and the `xmlns=` is to put the generated `Master` element in the correct namespace.  You could do without the default namespace if you used `<xsl:element name="Master" namespace="AAA" />` instead of `<Master/>` within the template, but the ns2 and 3 are definitely required.

Comment: I've just tried this and it works exactly as you said - thank you ever so much.

Comment: I have a last question. I tried adding the xmlns:frog on the everyone element with the template you suggested but it didn't make any difference to the output. I put the template that matches a Person with no firstname at the end of the XSL doc. Is the order of the templates I've got correct?

Comment: @user2119994 The ordering should make no difference. I tested the full stylesheet including the `/*` template using `xsltproc` and it worked fine (apart from warnings about the namespace URIs not being proper URIs), what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xalan which looks like it behaves slightly differently than yours.