# Can't convert XML where <ns0:

Tags: xml, xslt

I've to convert xml file to csv file using XSLT.

But here, i've a technical issue with the ns0:, ns1:, etc...

i'm a beginner in XSLT/XML

Right now my xsl is similar to this one :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/XSD/1.0" 
            xmlns:ns1="http://www.42site.com/ship/5.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Day,Month,Year</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:parameters"/>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:parameters">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:Get/info"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="info">
        <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Month"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And i used this stylesheet for this kind of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns0:parameters xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/XSD/1.0">
        <ns1:Get xmlns:ns1="http://www.42site.com/ship/5.0">
            <info>
                <Day>31</Day>
                <Month>01</Month>
                <Year>2000</Year>
            </info>
        </ns1:Get>
   </ns0:parameters>
```

So as you can imagine, it doesn't work, the result is below:

```
day,month,year
```

and i expect this:

```
day,month,year
31,01,2000
```

I now have this error:

```
rulestest.xsl:2:97: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

PS: my last post was marked as existing questions, but can't find the solution.

Comment: Is the XML in your question exactly what you are using? Or does your real XML have namespace declarations in of the form `xmlns:ns0="http://...."`. If it does have these declarations, you should edit your question to show it. If not, then it will not be valid XML, and so you won't be able to use XSLT on it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i edited the post

Answer (score 2):

Your previous question was closed as a duplicate of the question [Add additional namespace with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138788/add-additional-namespace-with-xslt). This does contain the answer, as the first sentence says...

> First you need to declare the various namespaces in your stylesheet...

So, that just means adding the declarations of `ns0` and `ns1` to your `xsl:stylesheet` node

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/XSD/1.0" 
                xmlns:ns1="http://www.42site.com/ship/5.0">
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNy

Note that with your current XSLT you should have really got an error along the lines of `Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns0`

Comment: Like you said, i've a prefix error, " the prefix for xsl:stylesheet isn't bound... Thanks for the live testing link !

Comment: You should always remember to put any errors you are getting in your question. Thank you!